# Word Count in Javascript

Tags: javascript, word-count

I know I have already asked this but it doesn't seem to work,

I have the following

```
var value = $('#RichHtmlField_displayContent').text();


if (value.length == 0) {
    $('#show_word_count').html(0);
    return;
}

var wordCount = value.split(/[\s.?]+/g).length

  $('#show_word_count').html(wordCount);
};
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#RichHtmlField_displayContent').change(counter);
    $('#RichHtmlField_displayContent').keydown(counter);
    $('#RichHtmlField_displayContent').keypress(counter);
    $('#RichHtmlField_displayContent').keyup(counter);
    $('#RichHtmlField_displayContent').blur(counter);
});
```

but it keeps adding the last work of first sentence to the first word of the next sentence if there is a full stop its ok but if there isn't it keeps adding it and views it as one word

Any help

Comment: `java` is not `javascript`

Comment: And if you have asked this... Do edit that question.. Why are you posting it again ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [word count method](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1751059/word-count-method)

Comment: sorry didn't know how to add to the other asked questions...sorry

Comment: `$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#RichHtmlField_displayContent').on('change keydown keypress keyup blur', function () {
        $('#show_word_count').text($(this).split(/\s+/).length);
    });
});`

Comment: tried that didn't work...can you put the whole code might be something wrong...